# Transpose data into multiple column using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file which has two columns Phone and Type. Now I need to transpose these two columns into three columns based on the Type value(Type will have three values only i.e. Home,Office and Personal)

Source data example:

```
ID|Phone|Type
1|123#345#567|Home#Office#Personal
2|890|Office
3|431#676|Personal#Home
```

Output req:

```
ID|Home|Office|Personal
1|123|345|567
2||890|
3|676|431|
```

I am able to map the Phone with their types, but struggling to split the values in separate columns, here is snippet of my code:

```
zipped = zip(df['Phone'],df['Type'])

df['PhoneData'] = ['|'.join(','.join(y).rstrip('|')
                                   for y in zip(a.split('#'), b.split('#')))
                          for a, b in zipped]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a DataFrame from a list of dictionaries where each dictionary's keys and values are column names and values respectively, so this will do the job:

```
text = '''Phone|Type
123#345#567|Home#Office#Personal
890|Office
431#676|Personal#Home'''

pd.DataFrame([
    dict(zip(type.split('#'), phone.split('#'))) 
        for phone, type in map(lambda t: t.split('|'), text.splitlines()[1:])
])
```

If your data isn't in text but as a dataframe,

```
df['Phone'] = df['Phone'].str.split('#')
df['Type'] = df['Type'].str.split('#')

df.explode(['Phone', 'Type']).set_index('Type', append=True).unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1)
```

Comment: Nice answer .. +1. Good use of `append=True` in set_index.

Comment: @kunalsharma If you see error `ValueError: column must be a scalar`, your pandas version maybe older. Either upgrade it or use command : `df.apply(pd.Series.explode).set_index('Type', append=True).unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1)` .

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It's good to know about that!

Comment: This command is giving me the same output as I was doing in zip :
             Phone                      Type
0  [123, 345, 567]  [Home, Office, Personal]
1            [890]                  [Office]
2       [431, 676]          [Personal, Home]

I was working on to get output like:
ID|Home|Office|Personal
1|123|345|567
2||890|
3|676|431|